# Definite Integral of square root of polynomial

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to learn how to find the **definite** integral of  the square root of a polynomial such as: 
    $$\sqrt{36x + 1}$$ or $$\sqrt{2x^2 + 3x + 7} $$

**EDIT:** It's not guaranteed to be of the same form. It could be any polynomial that can't be easily factored into squares.

This isn't homework, I'm studying for a final. And for context, I'm finding the arc length of a function.

Comment: Try  $u=36x+1$..

Comment: So you want to integrate $\sqrt{P(x)}$. If $P(x)$ is a linear or quadratic polynomial, we can integrate in terms of elementary functions. In general, if the degree of $P(x)$ is $\ge 3$, $\sqrt{P(x)}$ does not have an elementary antiderivative except in quite special cases.

Comment: This is a longshot, but, is there an efficient way to compute it?

Comment: @AndréNicolas where can I find the proof of the conclusion?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Recall that for $\alpha \neq -1$, we have
$$\int (ax+b)^{\alpha}dx = \dfrac1a \cdot \dfrac{(ax+b)^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1} + \text{ constant}$$
A way to see the above is as follows. Let $y = ax+b$. We then have $dy = adx$. Hence for $\alpha \neq -1$,
$$\int (ax+b)^{\alpha}dx = \int y^{\alpha} \dfrac{dy}a = \dfrac1a \dfrac{y^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1} + \text{ constant} = \dfrac1a \dfrac{(ax+b)^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1} + \text{ constant}$$
If $\alpha = -1$, we then have
$$\int \dfrac{dx}{ax+b} = \dfrac{\log(ax+b)}a + \text{ constant}$$

---

In general, there is no easy way to get $$\int \sqrt{P(x)} dx,$$ if degree of $P(x)$ is greater than $2$.

If $P(x)$ is linear, i.e., has degree $1$, I have mentioned above how to proceed.

Below we will see how to proceed if $P(x)$ is quadratic, i.e., $$P(x) = ax^2 + bx + c = a ((x+b_1)^2 + c_1).$$
$$b_1=\frac{a}{2b}$$ $$c_1=\frac{c}{a}-b_1^2$$

We now have the following
$$\sqrt{P(x)} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{(x+b_1)^2 \pm c_1}$$
which gives us that
$$\int \sqrt{P(x)} dx = \sqrt{a} \int \sqrt{(x+b_1)^2 + c_1} dx$$
and
$$\int \sqrt{(x+b_1)^2 + c_1} dx = \dfrac{(b_1+x)\sqrt{P(x)} + c_1 \log \left(b_1 + x + \sqrt{P(x)}\right)}2 + \text{constant}$$

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Sorry for not being more explicit, but I need a more general solution. It's not guaranteed to be ax+b

Comment: @notbad.jpeg Your question wants the integral of $\sqrt{36x+1}$. This means $\alpha = \dfrac12$, $a = 36$ and $b=1$.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Why are you assuming $a$ positive?

Comment: In "we now have", it seems that the c term gains an unnecessary square as in $c_{1}^{2}$

Comment: Where does the last formula come from?

Comment: $$\text{Shouldn't} \;\;\; b_1 = \frac{b}{2a}$$

Answer (score 6):

$$\int {\sqrt{36x+1}}\,dx$$

use this formula

$$\int {\sqrt{x}}\,dx=\frac {x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac32}\implies \frac {2x^\frac32}{3}+C$$

so
$$\int {\sqrt{36x+1}}\,dx=\frac {2(36x+1)^\frac32}{(3)(36)}$$
$$\frac {(36x+1)^\frac32}{54}+C$$

## Q2

$$\int\sqrt{2x^2 + 3x + 7}\,dx $$
$$\int\sqrt{2(x^2 + \frac{3x}{2} + \frac72)}\,dx $$
$$\int\sqrt{2(x^2 + \frac{3x}{2} + \frac72)}\,dx $$
$$\sqrt2\int\sqrt{(x^2 + \frac{3x}{2} + \frac72)}\,dx $$
$$\sqrt2\int\sqrt{(x^2 + \frac{3x}{2} + \frac72+\frac{3^2}{4^2}-\frac{3^2}{4^2})}\,dx $$
$$\sqrt2\int\sqrt{(x^2 + \frac{3x}{2} +\frac{3^2}{4^2}+ \frac72-\frac9{16})}\,dx $$
$$\sqrt2\int\sqrt{(x+ \frac{3}{4})^2 + \frac72-\frac9{16})}\,dx $$
$$\sqrt2\int\sqrt{(x+ \frac{3}{4})^2 + (\frac{\sqrt47}{4})^2}\,dx $$

now use this formula
$$\int{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\,dx=\frac{x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}{2}+\frac{a^2\log|x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}|}{2}+C$$
I hope you can take it now on your own

Comment: I think that's the same as u-substitution

Comment: yes it is same as u substitution.But I do not use subs. if question is in standard form of any basic formula

Answer (score 5):

For a linear polynomial under the radical a $u$-substitution will do. If you wish to solve this problem for higher order polynomials *in the general case* then you will be appealing to a lot of algebra, hyperbolic trig functions, and [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) (which are similar in that they are arclength problems). In short there is no easy short cut to solve this problem for arbitrary degree polynomials.

For degree one polynomials, do as the other answers have advised. For degree two polynomials, like $\sqrt{2x^{2}+3x+7}$, you should employ trigonometric substitutions.

Step 1: Given $\int\sqrt{ax^{2}+bx+c}$ first complete the square into something of the form $k\int\sqrt{\pm u^{2}\pm l}$.

Step 2: Using one of the three substitutions from [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) on the matter to get the integral into the form of $k\int\sqrt{f(x)^{2}}$ for some trig function $f(x)$.

Step 3: Remove the radical and solve using known integrals.

If you wish to venture into solving cubics (or higher degree polys) in the general case (i.e. not reducible by a substitution) then do read up on elliptic integrals.

Comment: user17762's method with logarithms is more concise and general, but the trig function one is often easier to recall on the fly in exams.

Answer (score 4):

Using the $u$-substitution $u = 36x + 1$, we have $du = 36dx$. Then, it follows that:

$$\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{36x+1}dx = \frac{1}{36}\int_{36a+1}^{36b+1}u^{\frac{1}{2}}du = \frac{1}{36}*\frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}|^{36b+1}_{36a+1} = \frac{1}{54}(36x+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}|^{b}_{a}$$

Comment: This works, but I thought that I could complete the square or something like that.

Comment: @notbad.jpeg, the polynomial under the radical is not a quadratic, so completing the square doesn't quite work here. For your more general question, see André Nicolas's comment.