# How to find $\int\sqrt{(26x-x^2)}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I find $\int \sqrt{(26x-x^2)} dx $

Is this an integration by parts question?

Thanks,

--Nick

Comment: I corrected the latex formatting. Can the OP please check that the formula is correct? Is the square root over the entire argument? Ok... I see editing is ongoing :-)

Comment: Sorry I may have just undone your work. The square root is around 26x-x^2. I am new to this.

Comment: No problem. You can write the square root in latex in this way: \sqrt{} with curly braces. Everything in the curly braces will be below the square root.

Comment: This may be helpful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390080/definite-integral-of-square-root-of-polynomial

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First notice that $26x-x^{2}=-(x^{2}-26x)=-((x-13)^{2}-169)=169-(x-13)^{2}$

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Using Trigonometric Substitution,   $$2ax-x^2=a^2-(x-a)^2$$

Set $$x-a=a\sin\theta$$

Here $a=13$

Answer (score 0):

Note
\begin{align}\int{\sqrt{26x-x^2}dx}& = \int{\sqrt{169-(x^2-26x+169)}dx} \\
&=\int{\sqrt{13^2-(x-13)^2}dx}
\end{align}
It can be evaluated using $x-13=13\sin t,0\leq t \leq \pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate as follows

\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{26x-x^2} dx &=
\int \frac{\sqrt{26x-x^2}}{2(x-13)}d[(x-13)^2]\\
&=\frac12(x-13)\sqrt{26x-x^2}+ \frac{169}2\int\frac1{ \sqrt{26x-x^2}}dx\\
&= \frac12(x-13)\sqrt{26x-x^2}+\frac{169}2\sin^{-1}{\frac {x-13}{13}}+C\\
\end{align}