# Integral of square root of polynomial

Tags: calculus, integration

In [Definite Integral of square root of polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390080/definite-integral-of-square-root-of-polynomial) , André Nicolas commented: "So you want to integrate $\sqrt{P(x)}$. If $P(x)$ is a linear or quadratic polynomial, we can integrate in terms of elementary functions. In general, if the degree of $P(x)$ is $\ge 3$, $\sqrt{P(x)}$ does not have an elementary antiderivative except in quite special cases. "

Is this conclusion a theorem? where could I find more details of it?

Comment: I suppose that with degree 3, you face already the nightmare of elliptic integrals (with nasty arguments moreover) or very special functions. Just for the fun of it, use Wolfram Alpha, type **integrate sqrt((x-a)(x-b)(x-c))** and .... enjoy !

Comment: I guess it may come from [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra))

Comment: @A.Γ. but how wouldd Liouville's theorem arrive the conclusion?