# Integral of $\int\ e^{-x/2}\sqrt(sin-1)/(cosx+1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$\int\ e^{-x/2}\sqrt(sin-1)/(cosx+1)$

The result that I'm getting here contains a cosecx term but the answer has secx term!
Please help.

Comment: Do you mind showing your work? It will help us see what you have tried and where you lacked.

Comment: You say you completed the square ... what about looking for a suitable substitution once you have it in the form    $\int \sqrt(2(x+\frac{3}{4})^2+\frac{23}{8}dx$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390080/definite-integral-of-square-root-of-polynomial

Comment: Did you just edit the question ? If you have another doubt, kindly ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the integral?

$$\int{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\ln(\frac{{x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{a})+C$$

Comment: There’s an $x$ missing ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, Mathjax error. Fixed. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: yes I do know it and ya thanks I got the answer.

Comment: @Ankush, Then please upvote the answers and accept one which likely helped you. Also welcome to MSE.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Substitute $z=(x+\frac{3}{4})$ after completing the square.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the so-called Euler Substitution:
$$\sqrt{2x^2+3x+4}=x\sqrt{2}+t$$
then we get
$$x=\frac{t^2-4}{3-2t\sqrt{2}}$$
$$dx=\frac{-2\sqrt{2}t^2+6t-8\sqrt{2}}{(3-2t\sqrt{2})^2}dt$$
and
$$\sqrt{2x^2+3x+4}=\frac{-\sqrt{2}t^2+3t-4\sqrt{2}}{3-2t\sqrt{2}}$$