# How to solve an integral with a quadratic polynomial inside a square root?

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

Given the function $c(t)=(t, t, t^2)$ what is its arclength from $1 \le t \le 2$?

I find the derivative and its norm, but am stuck at how to solve the integral:

$$\int\sqrt{ax^2 + b} dx$$

Comment: what kind of function is $c'(t)$? i find the notation very strange, is it a parametrized vector? why first two coordinates coincide?

Comment: @pointguard0 my apologies I accidentally added a derivative where it was not supposed to be, I've updated my answer

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390080/definite-integral-of-square-root-of-polynomial) might be what you are looking for

Comment: What is $a,b$, are they in $\mathbb{R}^{\ge0}$ or just in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: In any table of integrals or symbol-manipulation program:  $$\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{a x^2+b}+\frac{b \log \left(\sqrt{a} \sqrt{a x^2+b}+a x\right)}{2
   \sqrt{a}}$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Let $$x^2=\frac ba\tan^2 \phi.$$