# Calculate $f(x)=\int_1^x \sqrt{t(3t-2)} \, dt$

Tags: calculus, functions, definite-integrals

I am struggling with this integral calculation.

Calculate:

$$f(x)=\int_1^x \sqrt{t(3t-2)} \, dt$$

for $x\geq 0$

Comment: What part exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Can you explain what technique needs to be used?

Comment: A series of substitutions should work

Comment: Take a look here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390080/definite-integral-of-square-root-of-polynomial

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $u = 3t - 2\implies\mathrm dt = 3\,\mathrm du$. Therefore,

$$\int\sqrt{t(3t - 2)}\,\mathrm dt\equiv\frac1{3^{3/2}}\int\sqrt{u^2 + 2u}\,\mathrm du = \int\sqrt{(u + 1)^2 - 1}\,\mathrm du$$

Let $u + 1 = \sec (v)\implies\mathrm du = \sec(v)\tan(v)\,\mathrm dv$. Therefore,
$$\begin{align}\int\sqrt{(u + 1)^2 - 1}\,\mathrm du&\equiv\int\sqrt{\sec^2(v) - 1}\sec(v)\tan(v)\,\mathrm dv \\ &= \int\sec(v)\tan^2(v)\,\mathrm dv \\ &= \int\sec^3(v) - \sec(v)\,\mathrm dv\end{align}$$

From here, linearity is your friend. Notice that the reduction formula for $$\int\sec^nx\,\mathrm dx$$ is well known. You fill find at the end that the integral is only defined for $x\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Complete square

$$f(x)=\int_1^x \sqrt{3t^2-2t} \> dt = \frac1{\sqrt3} \int_1^x\sqrt{(3t-1)^2-1}\>dt$$

and let $3t-1=\cosh u$. Then

\begin{align}
f(x)=&\ \frac1{3\sqrt3}\int_{\cosh^{-1}2}^{\cosh^{-1}(3x-1)}\sinh^2 u \, du\\
=& \ \frac1{6\sqrt3}\left(-u+\sinh u\cosh u\right) \bigg|_{\cosh^{-1}2}^{\cosh^{-1}(3x-1)}\\
=& \ \frac1{6\sqrt3}\left(\cosh^{-1}2-\cosh^{-1}(3x-1)+\sqrt3(3x-1)\sqrt{3x^2-2x} -2\sqrt3 \right)
\end{align}