# Integration of functions of type $\sqrt[m]{k\alpha x^2}$

Tags: integration, analysis

> I would like some help in integrating a function like that:
>
> $$\int\sqrt[3]{4\alpha x^2}dx$$
>   for $a\in \mathbb{R}^+.$

More generally, what's the heuristic for dealing with functions of the type:

$$\int\sqrt[m]{k\alpha x^2}dx$$
for $m\in \mathbb{N}^*,$ $k\in \mathbb{N}^*,$ $a\in \mathbb{R}^+.$

> What about $$\sqrt[m]{kP(x)}dx$$
>   for $m\in\mathbb{N}^*, \ k\in \mathbb{N}^*,$ $a\in \mathbb{R}^+ $ and $P(x)$ a polynomial (you can add more hypotheses if needed) ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.   $\large\int\sqrt[3]{4\alpha x^2}dx=$ $(4\alpha)^{1/3}\large\int x^{2/3}dx$ $=(4\alpha)^{1/3}\dfrac35 x^{(5/3)}+C$

Comment: Is there anything you can tell us about the function $P(x)$? Is $P(x)$ a polynomial?

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard edited thanks

Comment: Integral $\int\sqrt{P(x)}\;dx$ where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $3$ or $4$ is an elliptic integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the first integral is really easy. You just need to separate the constants out.
$$I=\int\sqrt[m]{k\alpha x^2}\,dx$$
$$I=\sqrt[m]{k\alpha}\int x^{\frac2m}\,dx$$
$$I=\sqrt[m]{k\alpha}\cdot\frac {x^{\frac 2m+1}}{\frac 2m+1}$$
As for the second part, the method of solving depends highly on the nature of $P(x)$. There is no general solution to the integrals in this form.

Comment: +1. I'm waiting to see if someone adds anything useful about the general  polynomial case before accepting

Comment: A similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390080/definite-integral-of-square-root-of-polynomial) shows general solutions for $m=2$