# Length of a parametric curve passing though three points

Tags: calculus, integration, parametrization

I would like to compute the length of a parametric curve

$$
x(\xi) = -\frac{1}{2} \; x_1 \;\xi (1 - \xi) + x_2 \;(1 - \xi^2) + \frac{1}{2} \;x_3 \;\xi (1 + \xi) \\
y(\xi) = -\frac{1}{2} \;y_1 \;\xi (1 - \xi) + y_2 \;(1 - \xi^2) + \frac{1}{2} \;y_3 \;\xi (1 + \xi)
$$

that passes between three points $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$ in the limits $\xi = [-1, 1]$, using the formula:

$$
s = \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{d\xi}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{d\xi}\right)^2} d\xi
$$

---

My approach I've taken is to substitute the differentials

$$
\frac{dx}{d\xi} = \frac{1}{2}(a\xi + b) \\
\frac{dy}{d\xi} = \frac{1}{2}(c\xi + d)
$$

into the formula for the curve length which can now be written as

$$
s = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{e \xi^2 + f \xi + g} \; d\xi
$$

where

$$
\begin{align}
a &= 2 x_1 - 4x_2 + 2 x_3 \\
b &= x_3 - x_1 \\
c &= 2 y_1 - 4y_2 + 2 y_3 \\
d &= y_3 - y_1 \\
e &= a^2 + c^2 \\
f &= 2(ab + cd) \\
g &= b^2 + d^2 \\
\end{align}
$$

Finally I use the formula for the integral of the square root of a polynomial given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390080/definite-integral-of-square-root-of-polynomial) and arrive at

$$
s = \frac{\sqrt e}{4} \left[ (\xi + h) \left( \sqrt{(\xi + h)^2 + k} \right) + \log\left( \frac{\sqrt{(\xi + h)^2 + k} + (\xi + h)}{\sqrt k} \right) k \right]
$$

where

$$
\begin{align}
h &= \frac{f}{2e} \\
k &= \left(\frac{g}{e} - \frac{f}{4e^2} \right) \\
\end{align}
$$

Unfortunately the results of my calculation indicate that the above formula isn't correct.

The most worrying aspect of this solution is that $k \rightarrow \infty$ as $e \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Did you try to compute the antiderivative by yourself ? First, comple the square and then substitution.

Comment: Do you mean

$$
 e \xi^2 + f \xi + g = e \left[ \left(\xi + \frac{f}{2e} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{g}{e} - \frac{f}{4e^2} \right) \right]
$$

I did this as a prerequisite to applying the formula for the integral of the square root of a polynomial.