# Integrating functions of the form $\Big(\frac{P(t)}{Q(t)}\Big)^{1/2}$ where $P$ and $Q$ are quadratic polynomials of degree $\leq 2$

Tags: integration, rational-functions

There is a [general method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390080/definite-integral-of-square-root-of-polynomial) for integrating any function of the form $\sqrt{P(t)}$ where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq 2$. I was wondering if it possible to find

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{P(t)}{Q(t)}}dt$$

for polynomials $P$, $Q$ of degree $\leq 2$ using elementary functions.

Comment: In terms of elementary functions? No, not unless there are cancellable factors in the polynomials. In terms of elliptic integrals? Yes, always. https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~glabahn/Papers/ellipticPrePrint.pdf

Answer (score 0):

For degree $1$, it is quite simple to compute
$$I=\int \sqrt{\frac{x-a}{x-b}}\,dx$$ Let
$$u=\sqrt{\frac{x-a}{x-b}}\implies x=\frac{b u^2-a}{u^2-1}\implies dx=\frac{2 u (a-b)}{\left(u^2-1\right)^2}\,du$$ This makes
$$I=2(a-b)\int \frac{ u \sqrt{u^2} }{\left(u^2-1\right)^2}\,du=2(a-b)\int \frac{ u^2 }{\left(u^2-1\right)^2}\,du$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{ u^2 }{\left(u^2-1\right)^2}=-\frac{1}{4 (u+1)}+\frac{1}{4 (u+1)^2}+\frac{1}{4 (u-1)}+\frac{1}{4 (u-1)^2}$$ which is simple.

All other situations lead to monsters in terms of elliptic integrals.